# Corrupted macOS startup volume type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, apfs, data-recovery

My iMac was working (moving GB of files), when the electric current was taken by the energy provider close the current for works or any other reason. Now, the entire APFS container containing the startup volume is corrupted. (Can not be seen by Disk Utility, but can be seen with `diskutil list`.) Is there a way to recover the content? Or even better, restore the volume to working state without erasing it?

EDIT:

The problem is in `disk0s2` and can be solved easily using the following steps:

1. Boot to macOS Recovery (via internet).
2. You will need to replace `*start*` & `*size*` shown in this step with actual numbers for `disk0s2`, which can be found with:

   ```
   gpt -r show /dev/disk0
   ```

   The following commands can be used to fix the problem.

   ```
   diskutil umountDisk disk0                                                      
   gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0                                                   
   diskutil umountDisk disk0                                                        
   gpt add -i 2 -b *start* -s *size* -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
   ```
3. Enter the following to verify the volume is mounted.

   ```
   cd /Volumes
   ls
   ```
4. Reboot back to macOS.

These steps solved my problem + all data is still there!

Comment: How old is your backup?  That's probably easier.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: Riccardo: The idea is to post the question separate from any answers. So, could you post an answer instead of placing the answer in the question? Also, you can return later and accept you own answer. This will tell others a solution was found.

Comment: I can confirm that the solution the OP has posted has worked for my computer, MacOS Catalina 10.15.7